# GUI-based force field optimization with bond-typing

Tags: one-topic-per-answer, software-recommendations

I am looking for a list of programs that support structure relaxations via molecular mechanics (e.g. via UFF) with the following conditions:

1. The program is free (free with an academic license is okay)
2. It works on materials with periodic boundary conditions
3. It can read/write CIF
4. It has a GUI
5. It supports automatic bond-typing that can be adjusted via the GUI if desired

An example of a commercial program that can do this is Materials Studio. I'm looking for free alternatives, however.

Comment: +1 I see this becoming another valuable list that will also help a lot of future users too! Thanks for the good question!

Comment: Avogadro fulfills most of them. I believe it can handle pbc, but I am not completely sure.

Comment: is this for small molecules, or proteins? The requirement for PBC suggests some kind of simulation box, so are you also looking for relaxation of water molecules?

Comment: @lewiso1, it's for crystalline materials.

Comment: @ShoubhikRMaiti with 3 days left on the bounty and no answers yet, I wanted to check how this question was doing, and noticed your comment here. After searching "avogadro periodic boundary conditions" I did get some results such as [this](https://discuss.avogadro.cc/t/viewing-multiple-unit-cells-in-periodic-boundary-conditions/74). It seems to satisfy requirements 1-4, what about #5? If it satisfies all, maybe you could write an answer with more details?

Comment: @NikeDattani Hi, I have checked with Avogadro on my pc, and even though it can build crystal structures, it doesn't seems to be able to use the periodicity when optimizing with forcefields. Maybe there is some option hidden somewhere that I don't know. It does satisfy #5. It satisfies everything except #2. I can write an answer, but I don't know if Andrew is specifically looking for #2.

Comment: @ShoubhikRMaiti Andrew probably wants something that satisfies all 5 criteria. It's his bounty, so I'll let him decide whether he would prefer to at least be able to "award it" to an answer that "comes close" to solving his problem, or would prefer to just let the bounty dissolve (since having the question remain in the "unanswered" list will make it more likely to get an answer in the future). The 7-day limit on bounties is an unfortunate characteristic of the SE network, but we also have [this](https://mattermodeling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/109/5) if Andrew wants to try again with longer.

Comment: @ShoubhikRMaiti -- Thanks for your reply. Unfortunately, the support for PBCs is among the most important since I am interested in crystalline materials. There are several great options for molecules out there, including Avogadro and others.

Comment: Bounty grace period ends in 2 minutes. Unfortunately with questions like these, there might actually not be any answer at all. Similarly you said [here](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/a/4746/5) that you might have put too many constraints on the "functionals for transition metals" question. One thing you could do is reduce the # of constraints, so that the "several great options" you said exist, can be listed: **This brings more attention to the question than any possible bounty** [cot'd...]

Comment: as being in the HNQ list can mean 4k views [as this question got](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/4501/5) without a bounty as opposed to the 75 yours got even with a bounty. Unfortunately the answers you get this way might describe things you already know (though they'll certainly be helpful to others), but then you could put a bounty saying that you'll accept the answer that also works with PBCs, and with the thousands of views that your "highly active question" is getting, it might help increase your chances of getting what you want. There's pros and cons of both strategies though

Comment: As @AndrewRosen probably knows, there was an effort to provide periodic UFF in Avogadro through a patch to Open Babel. It’s non trivial. The new force field framework in Avo2 will support plugins for optimization using other programs, but isn’t ready yet.

Comment: Suffice to say that I’ll add an answer to the question when Avo2 can meet the needs here.

Comment: @GeoffHutchison, I figured you'd stop by, and of course I look forward to when Avogadro2 can handle the job!

Answer (score 7):

### GDIS

I think GDIS accomplishes your conditions. As it is an interface (like Material Studio) you will need to install some packages to run the tasks. As you are interested in using molecular mechanics (with UFF), I recommend to install also the [GULP](https://gulp.curtin.edu.au/gulp/) package, specialized in molecular dynamics and in lattice dynamics.

> GDIS is a GTK based program for the display and manipulation of
> isolated molecules and periodic systems. It is in development, but is
> nonetheless fairly functional.

It has the following features:

- Support for several file types (CIF, BIOSYM, XYZ, XTL, MARVIN, and GULP)
- OpenGL rendering (requires gtkglarea)
- Assorted tools for visualization (measurements, ribbons, polyhedral display)
- Useful manipulation tools, including matrix transformations and periodic image display.
- Powerful surface generation and crystal morphology tools.
- Animation of BIOSYM and GULP trajectory files

GDIS also allows you to perform the following functions through other packages:

- Model rendering (courtesy of POVRay)
- Energy minimization (courtesy of GULP)
- Morphology calculation (courtesy of cdd)
- Space group processing (courtesy of SgInfo)
- View the Periodic Table (courtesy of GPeriodic)
- Load additional filetypes, such as PDB (courtesy of Babel)

Site: http://gdis.seul.org/